# Process to process remote communication

Tags: c++, service, process, client-server, remotecommand

I have 2 processes running on 2 different machines. 
What is the best way to communicate between those to send instructions WITHOUT using any username/password?

Language : C++

Comment: Is that your only requirement? What kind of data are you going to send over it? What volume? Which (if any) security/reliability guarantees do you want? What have you looked at? Currently your requirement is satisfied by "any low-level network protocol".

Comment: Use networking to communicate. You can search "Networking in C++"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many solutions with different pros and cons. Try googling for it.

Since you've not given any other requirements, the simplest way is via socket programming. Check out this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-cc/ for some basic knowledge and http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~moorthy/Courses/os98/Pgms/socket.html for examples.